# How to find an explicit formula for a recursive function?

Tags: recursive-algorithms

> Define 
>   $$ S_{n+1} = \frac{S_n^2+x}{2S_n}$$ and $S_1 = k$, where x,k > 0.
>   find an explicit formula for $S_n$ in terms of n.

I don't even know where to begin. I tried using algebraic manipulation to rid of $S_{n+1}$ but nothing is working. Since x needs to disappear I'm thinking we should use ratios.

Comment: They should be all small $s_n$.

Comment: Any starting value? i.e. $s_0$

Comment: Yes, $s_1 = k$ which is greater than 0, good catch, I'll edit the question. Also x is greater than 0.

Comment: You should change the capital $S$ to $s$ in the recurrence relation.

Comment: Does this problem come from applications?

Comment: My friend asked me how to solve this. It was in his Advanced Calculus homework. We had proven earlier that $S_n \ge S_{n+1}$

Comment: The $x$ isn't very important because you can rewrite your recurrence relation as $\frac{S_{n+1}}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2 + 1}{2\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt x} \right)}$ so a recurrence relation for $T_n = \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{x}}$ is just just $T_{n+1}=\frac{T_n^2 +1}{2T_n}$. In other words, you only need to deal with the case $x=1$. Note this could also be written as $T_{n+1} = \frac{T_n + \frac{1}{T_n}}{2}$ so that $T_{n+1}$ is the average of $T_n$ and its reciprocal.

Answer (score 4):

You can have the closed form

> $$S_n = \sqrt {x}\coth \left( 2^{n-1}{ \coth^{-1}} \left( {\frac {k}{\sqrt {x}}}
>  \right)\right) .$$

**Added:** If you want to find the limit without finding the closed form then you can advance as: assume $\lim_{n\to \infty } S_n = a $ then

> $$ a=\frac{a^2+x}{2a} \implies a= \pm \sqrt{x}.$$

Comment: That's a start but I think it wants it solely in terms of n.

Comment: It is in terms of $n$!

Comment: Try $\frac{S_n}{S_{n+1}}$? or even $\frac{T_n}{T_{n+1}}$?

Comment: @AdamStaples The recurrence depends on $x$. You can't make it disappear.

Comment: That is true. Maybe I misunderstood the question. I don't have the problem in front of me in order to know how to change it to the correct problem. maybe it's the limit of the sequence? 
It said I should have something like (1*3*5*...*(2n-1))/(...) but I cannot recall exactly.

Comment: @science Is there a more general result or a way of deriving this result?

Comment: @DanielV: Yes there are.

Comment: @DanielV Notice the similarity of the recursion formula with the addition formula $\coth(2x) = \frac{\coth^2(x)+1}{2\coth(x)}$. If $a_n = \coth(2^n\alpha)$ then the identity above implies that $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n^2 + 1}{2a_n}$. This type of procedure can be applied to other (trigonometric) addition formulas to get recursion formulas (or reversed engineered to find solutions). For example since $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ we have that $a_n = \sin(2^n \alpha)$ solves $a_{n+1} = 2a_n\sqrt{1-a_n^2}$.

Comment: So not really a general approach, but an interesting set of singular cases from trig ID.  Thanks~